# PHP скрипт грузит сервер

Tags: php, mysql

При запуске очень сильно нагружает сервер, при постоянной работе доходит до 100 и вырубает сервак.
Что можно сделать?
Данные в файле:
текст|текст|текст|текст|текст

```
    <?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
require 'rb.php';
R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=***********', '***********', '**********');
if (!R::testconnection()) {
    exit('Соединение с базой потеряно...');
}

//R::debug(true);

function readTheFile($path) {
    $handle = fopen($path, "r");

    while(!feof($handle)) {
        yield trim(fgets($handle));
    }

    fclose($handle);
}

$count = 0;

$iterator = readTheFile("shakespeare.txt");

foreach ($iterator as $iteration) {
$dp = explode("|",$iteration);
        $count++;


                    R::findOrCreate('proxy', [
                    'proxyip' =>$dp[0] ,
                   'type' =>$dp[1] ,
                    'country' =>$dp[2] ,
                    'level' =>$dp[3] ,
                    'region' =>$dp[4] ,
                    'continent' =>$dp[5]]); 



}

print $count . PHP_EOL;

require "memory.php";
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вероятнее всего проблема в redbean

Comment: какой есть выход?

Comment: Попробуйте через PDO сделать

Comment: я предлагаю вам переделать findOrCreate - дело в том что запись в базу - дорогостоящая операция, по сравнению с чтением. Когда вы записываете - чтение невозможно если это mysql MYISAM. Рекомендую записывать по 500 строк в одном запросе, а до этого их копить. Также в class R добавить деструктор - чтобы записать оставшийся кусок не записанных данных. И еще в цикл добавить usleep (1000);